# Accessing values in expression using a macro

Tags: julia

I'm wondering whether it's possible to define a macro that can modify the values of an expression only if the values are of a specific type?

Here's a minimal example:

```
type Special
    x::Int
end

f1(s, n::Special) = println("f1", s, n)
f2(s, n::Special) = println("f2", s, n)

x1 = Special(3)
x2 = Special(5)

expr =  :(
    f1("this is f1", x1),
    f2("this is f2", x2)
    )
```

Now a macro *might* be able to examine the values of the arguments to the functions, determine that `x1` and `x2` are of type `Special`, run some function to modify their values, say by changing 3 to 4 and 5 to 2 (it might involve comparing two values), then pass the expression back to the caller. The final result would be equivalent to calling:

```
f1("this is f1", 4)
f2("this is f2", 2)
```

I found that it's possible to access the values in a macro via:

```
eval(eval(filter(x -> typeof(eval(x)) == Special, expr.args[1].args))[1]).x

=> 3
```

but although this works it looks wrong, and I'm might either be doing it wrong or trying to do something too way out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should **never** try to check types or values inside macros. Using `eval` to figure out the type or value of something in a macro may work in very limited situations, but it'll break in almost every real use. Instead, just have the macro insert a call to a generic function — that's where Julia excels at picking apart types (as method dispatch) and values (within the method):

```
munge_special(x::Special) = Special(x.x + 42)
munge_special(x) = x
macro do_something_special(x)
    return :(munge_special($(esc(x))))
end

julia> @do_something_special Special(2)
Special(44)

julia> @do_something_special 3
3
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. I'm rethinking my approach... :)